# How do I access Telerik HtmlAttributes values via javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, telerik

What do I need to do in order to query HtmlAttributes values on a Telerik DropDownList?  I know how to do this via jQuery, but what is the proper way to query these?

```
    @(Html.Telerik().DropDownListFor(model => model.BookingOfficeIdNew)
                             .Name("BookingOfficeIdNew")
                             .HtmlAttributes(new
                                 {
// How do I access these?
                                     @class = "PropertyProposedValueSelect",
                                     @delta = Model.BookingOfficeIdNew,
                                     @container = "BookingOfficeContainer",
                                     @updateFlag = "BookingOfficeIdChanged",
                                     @deltaValue = "BookingOfficeIdOld",
                                     @newValue = "BookingOfficeIdNew",
                                     @newText = "BookingOfficeNameNew"
                                 })
                             .ClientEvents(events => events
                               .OnChange("SelectListValueUpdated")
                                 .OnLoad("OnDropDownListLoad")
                                 .OnOpen("OnDropDownListOpen")
                               )
                             .BindTo(Model.BookingOfficeIdChanged ? @Html.ToSelectList(Model.BookingOfficeNameNew, Model.BookingOfficeIdNew, true) : ((SelectListItem)ViewData["DefaultSelectListPrompt"]).ToSelectList(true))
                             .SelectedIndex(0)
                             .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax().Select("RraOfficeSelectListWithPrompt", "Revision"))
                             )
```

**EDIT/Answer**: I opted for selecting the parent container, using the proper class name; as the Telerik DropDownList extension generates an input element with id = "BookingOfficeIdNew", whose parent div container has class ".t-dropdown".

$("#BookingOfficeIdNew").parent(".t-dropdown")

Comment: care to post the rendered html for those of use who are not asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

The values will be set on the HTML element that the DropDownList extension creates in HTML. Have a look at the HTML that is generated by this. I suspect this may work (Note: I've not actually used this specific Telerik control - I'm only guessing by others that I've used)

```
var newTextValue = $('#BookingOfficeIdNew').attr('newText');
```

**UPDATE**

As far as I'm aware you can either get it via jQuery or regular javaScript. The telerik control simply puts the HtmlAttributes you define into the HTML element that it uses for the control - What you do with them after that is up to you. It provides no mecahnism for dealing with it because you can already do this through jQuery or regular javaScript.

Comment: Nope; I've looked at the html of course, and the attribs are added to the containing div (telerik dropdownlists are not html select controls).  I can do this very easily via jquery and go around the telerik control, but I want to know if there is something in the telerik dropdownlist control code that will do it "properly"

Comment: Well, both Michael and I were trying to be helpful, yet it appears we've both been voted down for not understanding or misinterpreting your question and what you mean by "properly" (which wasn't defined in the original question). That's a bit of a poor show. (Sometimes, I really wonder why I bother!)

Comment: @gangelo You are not going to get a better answer than this. Definitely doesn't merit a downvote.

Comment: @ColinMackay - I think everyone is trying to be "helpful" for the most part, that is not what down-voting is for I imagine.  I down-voted you because (in your own words "suspect[ed]" your answer may work, and, that you were "guessing"; this is not helpful and not an answer, although if I can undo the down-vote, I will.

Comment: @Daniel - Can't get a better answer?  I don't think so, but perhaps the down-vote was a bit much :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with taking an educated guess. Take what you know about one part of a framework and apply it to another. If I never did that I'd never get anywhere. You don't relearn to drive each time you buy a new car. I take an educated guess that the gears are configured similarly. It may be that the reverse is below the 5th gear (like my Yaris), or it may be that I have to lift something a switch on the gear stick and move it our to the side of 1st. Either way, I can apply knowledge learned elsewhere to the current situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the attributes of the element via the getAttribute() method.

In this case the code would look something like:

```
document.getElementById('BookingOfficeIdNew').getAttribute('updateFlag');
```

Comment: Nope; I've looked at the html of course, and the attribs are added to the containing div (telerik dropdownlists are not html select controls).  I can do this very easily via jquery and go around the telerik control, but I want to know if there is something in the telerik dropdownlist control code that will do it "properly"